# C# MVC return errors per item in IList to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Lets assume i have the following ViewModels:

```
public class EmailFromViewModel 
{
    public IList<InviteEmailAddress> InviteEmailAddress {get; set;}
}
 public class InviteEmailModel
    {
        [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my View i have a for loop to present a name and email input so users can invite people to join. The view presents by default 3 input groups(3xname and 3x email) and can be expanded by a button that adds a new group. Now when the list is posted ill loop thru the email addresses and proces them. While processing it can be possible that one of the items returns an error, i dont want the proces to stop but i want it to just store this error message and return it back to the view so i can present the error at the form group that caused the error.
I'm kind of lost on how to store the errors and return them to the view to present them. Does any1 have an idea on how to achieve this?

Also my required validation is not perfect now because if someone only wants to invite 1 person then the validation will trigger for the 2nd and 3rd input group that i present. I still need to figure out on how to fix this.

Processing code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> InviteEmail(InviteViewModel inviteUser) 
{
            foreach (var i in inviteUser.InviteEmailAddresses)
            {
                var user = _userService.GetUsersByEmail(i.Email);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (!_userService.CanInviteUser(user.Id, i.DumpId))
                        //Dont return but save result and present to user.

                }
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Guid tokenId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    SecurityToken securityToken = new SecurityToken()
                    {
                        Token = tokenId
                    };
                    _securityTokenService.CreateSecurityToken(securityToken );
                    UserMailer.Invite(i.Email).Send();
                    //Dont return but save result and present to user.

                }
                else
                    //Dont return but save result and present to user.

            }
}
```

Comment: Post your current 'processing' code.

Comment: Done, but a little simplefied.

Comment: If you only want to allow one `InviteEmailAddress` then you initial view should only include one, and then have an add button to optionally add more. But you need to show how you are dynamically adding new items (I assume your using ajax in conjunction with the `BeginCollectionItem` helper?)

Comment: Also suggest you use the `[EmailAddress]` attribute rather that your `[RegularExpression]` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-(data)/performing-simple-validation-cs

On your cshtml page you can add a `Html.ValidationMessageFor` as a placeholder for the error message and in your controller you can add `ModelState.AddModelError` to specify the error message to show.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid triggering the validation code when only 1 or 2 invitees are specified you need to take the required attribute off the view model. Then in your processing code when you find an error you can use:

```
 ModelState.AddModelError ("key1","Some error message goes here");
```

If you are doing the processing inside a custom modelbinder then you need to use:

```
bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(....)
```

In your view you would use

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("Key1")
```

Of course the trick is to make sure "Key1" can be a value that can be calculated for each of the repeated fields (maybe based on the index of the field in the list such as "email1", "name2").